# How to measure execution time of each loop step in Scala?

Tags: scala

I wrote a piece of code which measures code execution time in Scala. I want to write such a code that measures and prints execution time of every step of for loop.

```
import scala.language.postfixOps

def time[T](block: => T): T = {
  val v0 = System.nanoTime()
  val res = block 
  val v1 = System.nanoTime()
  println("Execution time: " + (v1 - v0) + "nanoseconds")
  res

}

var list = time {1 to 10 by 1 toList} // Execution time: 419830nanoseconds
```

I get the exact result for this code. But I can't write for every step.

Comment: There is no loop. You are converting a `Range` to a `List`. Technically there is a loop within the implementation of `toList`. But it's not yours.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try

```
(1 to 10 by 1).foreach(time(_))
```

which outputs approximately

```
Execution time: 8517nanoseconds
Execution time: 603nanoseconds
Execution time: 364nanoseconds
Execution time: 329nanoseconds
Execution time: 339nanoseconds
Execution time: 295nanoseconds
Execution time: 341nanoseconds
Execution time: 312nanoseconds
Execution time: 442nanoseconds
Execution time: 346nanoseconds
```

Say you had some function applied to each element

```
def inc(i: Int): Int = i + 1
```

then you could measure each step like so

```
(1 to 10 by 1).foreach(v => time(inc(v)))
```

Comment: Yes, it works. I also have another question. I have a while loop and there are some if else blocks in it. I want to measure the execution time of the loop. What can I do in this situation?

Comment: @GulnarNecefova It is hard to tell without seeing the code. May I suggest opening a new question with exact code snippet you would like to measure and perhaps the way in which you tried to solve it. Don’t worry if it is not fully working.